# Use keyword this/super in base class gives subclass name

Tags: java, inheritance

Just do not understand how keywords ***this*** and ***super*** works in these cases. Here are 2 inheritance examples.
Main method is common.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SeaCreature dolphin = new Dolphin();
    dolphin.swim(); // Dolphin is swimming - in both cases
}
```

SeaCreature class is common.

```
class SeaCreature {
    public void swim() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is swimming");
    }
}
```

Dolphin class for the first case. In this case I would expect that ***this*** in swim() method gives SeaCreature object not Dolphin.

```
class Dolphin extends SeaCreature {
}
```

Dolphin class for second case. In this case I would expect that ***super*** in swim() method gives SeaCreature object not Dolphin.

```
class Dolphin extends SeaCreature {
    @Override
    public void swim() {
        System.out.println(super.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is swimming");
    }
}
```

However in both cases the result is "Dolphin is swimming". How this works?

Comment: The object is still a `Dolphin`.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893848/in-java-super-getclass-prints-an-unexpected-name-in-the-derived-class-why-is and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002433/in-java-super-getclass-prints-child-not-parent-why-is-that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion is probably coming from the `getClass()` method, which returns the runtime class of the object, which means you'll get back the class you instantiated, not a parent class, even if the method call takes place in a parent class.

I'd recommend hard-coding a string `"Dolphin"` or `"SeaCreature"`, and using those, which will probably help you visualize the calls better.

https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/polymorphism-in-java/

Comment: Alternatively `Dolphin.class.getSimpleName()` and `SeaCreature.class.getSimpleName()`, refactoring tools may find it easier to rename the classes that way.